# Android - Rotate image around center point?

Tags: android

How can I rotate a bitmap (not a view or canvas) around its center point when the user touches it and drags it?

I have tried loads of examples on stack overflow and none appear to work.

So far I have:

```
double r = Math.atan2(posX - dial.getWidth() / 2, dial.getHeight() / 2 - posY);
rotation = (int) Math.toDegrees(r);
```

Comment: Link to those answer? Current code you have? You need to give us some kind of starting point.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, you don't have useful code samples like how and where your bitmap should be rotated, and you don't have any patience.

Comment: Stop asking the same question over and over, it will only earn you a ban, not a good answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty. Flagging for moderator attention.

Answer (score 1):

Create `Matrix` then set rotate via [`setRotate(degrees)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setRotate%28float%29). Then use this matrix when creating new Bitmap: [`Bitmap.createBitmap(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20boolean%29)