# Rotate in Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - Rotate Dial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490277/android-rotate-dial)
>   [Android - Rotate image around center point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491579/android-rotate-image-around-center-point)

How can I rotate a bitmap (not a view or canvas) around its center point when the user touches it and drags it?

I have tried loads of examples on stack overflow and none appear to work.

So far I have:

```
double r = Math.atan2(posX - dial.getWidth() / 2, dial.getHeight() / 2 - posY);
rotation = (int) Math.toDegrees(r);
```

Comment: Why are you asking the same question four times? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490277/android-rotate-dial http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491148/android-rotate-image-around-center-point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491579/android-rotate-image-around-center-point